# excel sheet report Sorting

Tags: excel-formula, salesforce, report

We have requirement in which we have to pull a report based on the response and date. Here the tricky part is in a given month we should get the latest response (Which is YES or NO ) for the latest date of the given month.

For some accounts there are two reports generated (Lets say for a account x , two call reports are generated in February  i.e on 10 feb and one on 12 feb , Now comes the tricky part I need only the response i.e on 12feb i.e. it maybe true or false).. Please help me how to sort some 4000 records in excel sheet?

Comment: Your problem and questions are not clear, please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Let us know what code you are using. To sort this out, you need to pass a command which helps you to select only the unique records and then filter it with dates to display the latest one. It will do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks @HemangRindani !!